# Errors after npm run prod

Tags: css, npm, tailwind-css

I'm developing a small website with Laravel and Tailwind on shared hosting. I can use a command line tool on host. In the local environment tailwind works without problem but after `npm run prod` most of the Tailwind functionalities are missing and the app.css and app.js seem to have errors.

e.g. scaling on hover -> `transform hover:scale-105 duration-200` doesn't work on host.

I tried importing Tailwind with cdn but it can't be a permanent solution.

What am I doing wrong??
I looking for an answer for days with no luck

Comment: a pro tip for you that took me ages to learn .... you should not run npm run * on the production server ... instead run locally and then deploy the .js file. Once i read that the production server should not have the node_modules folder (don't ask me why)

Comment: What version of Tailwind do you run? 1.x or 2?

Comment: It's the Tailwind 2.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume locally you run `npm run dev` and on production `npm run prod`. By default the development version of Tailwind does not remove unused style specification. But when with `npm run prod` unused styles are [purged for production](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#overview) usage.

As you can read in the docs the the paths to your templates should be configured in the `purge` section of your `tailwind.config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './src/**/*.html',
    './src/**/*.vue',
    './src/**/*.jsx',
  ],
  // .. more ..
```

[See docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#basic-usage):

> This list should include any files in your project that reference any of your styles by name

If you don't configure these paths, Tailwind does not know which `class`es you use and will therefore purge all styles it does not find, f. ex. your `hover:scale-105`.

**Solution "dirty":**.
You run `npm run dev` in production which will result in a large build of your css, but fixes the problem for now.

**Solution "clean":**.
You configure your paths correctly, let Tailwind correctly recognize it and purge unused styles... and be happy.

You can test this also in your development environment by running `npm run prod` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The app.css file after `npm run production` still has some warnings and when I upload it in the host the warnings are becoming errors. Here is a screenshot.

[image: Screen shot from the host Panel]

However when I use the file after `npm run dev` everything works fine. Maybe I'm having collisions between Tailwind classes. I will come up with an answer.